# 42000 Syntax error in query when executing prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have been pulling my hair out trying to swap my current script over to PDO. I have simplified the MySQL query for this example, but the error remains even with this version.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM :table WHERE lastUpdate > :appDate';

try{
    $db = connect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':table', $table);
    $stmt->bindParam(':appDate', $appDate);

    foreach($tablesToCheck as $table){
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultset[] = $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
} catch(PDOException $e){
    print 'Error!: '.$e->getMessage().'<br/>';
}//End try catch
```

$stmt->errorInfo() returns:

```
( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near ''GroupName' WHERE lastUpdate > NULL' at line 1 )
```

Comment: You cannot use placeholders as table or column identifiers in a prepared statement.  `:table` is therefore not valid there.

Comment: Instead, check the input value of `$table` against a list of white-listed acceptable values and concatenate it into the query.

Comment: I suppose I could have the try-catch inside the foreach and use $table in the query. But thanks for that, I was not aware you could not use table or column place-holders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the revised code with Michael's help:

```
foreach($tablesToCheck as $table){
    $sql = 'SELECT *, \''.$table.'\' AS tableName FROM '.$table.' WHERE lastUpdate > :appDate';

    try{
        $db = connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appDate', $appDate);
        $stmt->execute();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            $resultset[] = $row;

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        print 'Error!: '.$e->getMessage().'<br/>';
    }//End try catch
}//End foreach
```